# Filtering URLs to allow only the ones that are publicly visible

Tags: java, security, http

Users in my app can send messages between them and they can embed images from public sites in the content. I'd like to download those images and store them in my own storage, so my app won't break when the images are deleted from the internet.

I'm corcened about the security implications.

- What if the user sends a message with a img src that starts with `http://localhost`. I'll be requesting my own server.
- What if the src is a private ip. I'll be connecting to servers in my private network.
- What if the src is a host that resolves to `127.0.0.1`.
- And other nasty ideas I can't think of.

What can I do in order to check I'm downloading an image from a public server and not hitting my owns.

I'm using standard Java.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, hence the comment, but how will you ensure that you are legally allowed to download such images? There may be funky copyright stuff, so besides the technical risk it's also a different kind of risk that you should take into account I think.

Comment: @lengyelg I thought the DCMA would protect an app in this case. DISCLAIMER: I'm NOT a lawyer.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский I'm not either, so I'm not sure and I'd rather not write something that's not true, but it's definitely something that should be sorted out before going live. Just wanted to raise attention.

Comment: @lengyelg good point! I hadn't thinked of it! You make me realize that proxying the images could be a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

There are front end and backend solutions for this.

Simply prevent your app from accepting such links. **Use patterns** to ensure certain things are filtered, for example, localhost links or abusive links. Even if they are shortened. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8151742/2110818

Or configure your **firewall** to ensure that ports 80 and 443 are not accessible on the machine that has the apache server. There's plenty you can do.

Which server are you using or are going to use to host your server? For example, you can **secure tomcat** or other servers and prevent things from happening like here: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-security

Also, one should try to prevent any kind of unvalidated redirect anyways even within their code. So, don't just focus on external threats, your own code could hurt you. Check this out to know more: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet

But, I think the most relevant solution to prevent internal and external threats is to configure your machine well and ensure the firewall covers all aspects. There are detailed guides for securing servers out there.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that making the ports 80 and 443 inaccessible (and presumably using another port instead. right?) won't provide a good protection unless the urls with explicitly specified ports are black listed.

Comment: Hi! I can create a whitelist/blacklist, but I was looking for a more secure approach. I can fail to blacklist some kind of URLs and that's a security problem. Also, how can I firewall the server, if that server it's a public. I can't block 80 or 443.